# What's the android design pattern for multiple pages?

Tags: android, design-patterns

I'm working on an android app that has a section that feels like an iPhone home screen. There's a bunch of pages that are essentially displaying the same data in different configurations and users should be able to quickly move between them. Generally there won't be more than 4 or 5 pages.

I could just replicate the experience with the iPhone home screen with multiple dots on the bottom of the page, but that doesn't feel very android-friendly. What's the design pattern in android for viewing and interacting with this type of view? I know the android home screen has a variant with dots, but I've never seen it used within an app.

Screenshots or links to existing apps would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stock Android launcher has left/right paging behavior on the home screen, and it's open source.

This is the Workspace class. Pay special attention to the `onTouchEvent` and `onInterceptTouchEvent` methods. The utility classes Scroller and VelocityTracker are used together to define the behavior for snapping to a page when the user lets go from a drag.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2/+/master/src/com/android/launcher2/Workspace.java

Comment: For anyone reading this answer today, the ViewPager class in the Android support library is a much easier and more standardized way of doing this now.

Answer (score 0):

Hootsuite uses this design pattern and it works well in my opinion. I don't think it affects the user experience on Android in a negative way. I find that the biggest problem with people porting iPhone applications to Android is the fact that they try to port every single design pattern over. I don't think what you're trying to implement will be an issue.